# Как поместить число с точкой в диапазон?

Tags: delphi

Представим, что у нас есть счетчик оборотов в градусах (от 0 до 360) и изменение значение текущего положения может задаваться извне (например, повернуть на +98.75 или -217.112 градусов), причем несколько изменений могут приходить подряд. Т.о. положение может принимать значения в широком диапазоне, от -999.(9) до 999.(9) (или даже больше). Положение надо вывести в интерфейс, и для удобства, надо его преобразовать в значение в диапазоне от 0.0 до 360.

Вопрос - как можно просто и лаконично привести число с точкой (значения от `-999.(9)` до `999.(9)`) привести к диапазону `0..359.(9)`. То есть нужен некий аналог остатка от целочисленного деления, но для числа с точкой.

Пример неоптимального решения:

```
if x >= 0 then
  newFloat := Frac(x / 360) * 360
else
  newFloat := (1 - Frac(x / 360)) * 360;
```

Как это можно записать проще и короче?

Comment: на 10 помножить не поможет? (или там не 1 разряд после запятой?)

Comment: @teran спецом взял 9 в скобочки чтобы показать, что точность нужна больше, чем 1 знак после точки. Дополнил вопрос, спс за указание

Comment: Раз пошла такая пьянка, то почему бы не усилить условие задачи?  Сократить запись до одного символа!

Comment: @Sergey не совсем понимаю на что направлен ваш сарказм. Если код можно записать проще и короче - это же однозначно лучше. Тем более, что применений может быть гораздо больше и они могут быть более требовательны к производительности или компактности записи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Более компактный вариант, в котором мы просто прибавляем 360 после проверки знака:

```
newFloat := FMod(x, 360) + IfThen(x < 0, 360);
```

Прим.: ф-я `IfThen` отмечена как `inline`, т.е. она почти наверняка будет выполнена "на месте".

Answer (score 1):

Один из возможных вариантов - двойное использование `FMod`. Код получается следующим (результат `FMod` будет иметь знак первого аргумента, поэтому приходится делать двойное приведение диапазона):

```
newFloat := FMod(FMod(x, 360) + 360, 360);
```

---

Функция `FMod` появилась в Delphi XE8, и выглядит вот так и находится в `System.Math`:

```
// FMod returns the remainder of ANumerator / ADenominator
// (like mod in integers) with the same sign as ANumerator 
function FMod(const ANumerator, ADenominator: Single): Single;
begin
  Result := ANumerator - Trunc(ANumerator / ADenominator) * ADenominator;
end;
```

Comment: Стоит отметить, что результат FMod будет иметь знак первого аргумента, поэтому вам пришлось двойное приведение диапазона делать. Однако это невыгодно, два деления, и лучше написать свою функцию, взяв внутренность  fmod, и прибавив 360 после проверки знака

Comment: @MBo отличное замечание! Не хотите разместить как ответ?

Comment: Нет, ваш ответ дополнить - и хорошо будет.

Comment: @MBo сделал два ответа, т.к. 2 разных варианта по сути )

Comment: О, отлично, ifthen c начальным аргументом хорошо использовано.

Comment: @MBo третий параметр у `IfThen` необязательный, он по умолчанию и так `0`.

Comment: О, пардон, я в Math заглядывал, но в имплементацию, а не в объявление

Comment: Немного неудобно, конечно, что имплементация от объявления так отличаться может. Лучше бы все же строгое соответствие было (даже несмотря на дублирование текста) или никакого )